onDrag - no feedback when drag ends
I've been exploring SwiftUI's onDrag modifier and got a little stumped by the fact that there doesn't seem to be any feedback when it ends. Some people suggested wiring and action to the NSItemProvider's deinit and that solves some of the cases but there is one case in particular that it doesn't as it seems like SwiftUI is leaking the NSItemProvider instance. Here's a minimal setup to reproduce the issue:
import SwiftUI

struct DragDropDebugView: View {
    @State private var isDragging = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(isDragging ? "Dragging" : "Not dragging")
            Color.red
                .onDrag(
                    {
                        isDragging = true
                        return DraggableItemProvider {
                            self.isDragging = false
                        }
                    },
                    preview: {
                        Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}

private final class DraggableItemProvider: NSItemProvider {
    private var deinitAction: () -> Void

    init(deinitAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("DraggableItemProvider init")
        self.deinitAction = deinitAction
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        print("DraggableItemProvider deinit")
        deinitAction()
    }
}

If I long press to trigger the drag action, drag the item around and release, this setup works correctly and I can see DraggableItemProvider deinit being printed. If I just long press and release without dragging it around the deinit is never printed and I can see the leaked instance in the memory graph:

Does anyone know a way around this issue?

I would interpret the intention of the available API as follows:

The scope of "Drag Objects" is limited to their presentation and providing of data.
The scope of "Drop Destinations" is limited to observing compatible drag objects in their target area.

=>

The API does not offer any way to track what happens to dragged objects, except as observed by a viable drop destination.
The lifecycle of an NSItemProvider is not a reliable indication for a drag operation's state. (I assume it will be cleaned up sooner or later, and that there is no real memory leak.)

So, accepting these limitations, we have to find either a compatible implementation, or another solution altogether (i.e custom drag handling or library.)
Here is a simple, idiomatic solution with behavior similar but not identical to your attempt.
struct DragDropDebugView: View {
    @State private var isDragActive = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(isDragActive ? "Dragging" : "Not dragging")
            Color.red
                .draggable(Data())
        }
        .onDrop(of: [.data], isTargeted: $isDragActive) { _ in true }
    }
}


Thanks for your insights Roy. Unfortunately the real life application I'm working on is more complex than the example and adding an all encompassing onDrop area would be less than ideal
